# Concatenate the result of multiple case when statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to display a concatenation of multiple string built upon when statement when the condition is met. As follow :

```
select

case
  when T1.Field is not null then 'T1,' 
  when T2.Field is not null then /*last results*/ + 'T2,' 
  when T3.Field is not null then /*last results*/ + 'T3,'
end


from T1 
left outer join T2 on ...
left outer join T3 on ...
```

Comment: Do you want those literal strings (`'T1,'`), or do you want to actually select the `Field` column values?

Comment: I want the literal string 'T1' i just care if Field is null or not but i dont care the value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found out ... I didn't realize this was possible before :

```
select

  case when T1.Field is not null then 'T1,' else '' end
+ case when T2.Field is not null then 'T2,' else '' end
+ case when T3.Field is not null then 'T3,' else '' end as result

from T1 
left outer join T2 on ...
left outer join T3 on ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just try using [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)?

Something like

```
ISNULL(T1.Field,'') + ISNULL(T2.Field,'') + ... + ISNULL(TN.Field,'')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but if i want to display 'T1' instead of the content of the T1.field ???

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the plus signs '+' to double-vertical bars '||' in order to concatenate the text:

```
select

  case when T1.Field is not null then 'T1,' else '' end
|| case when T2.Field is not null then 'T2,' else '' end
|| case when T3.Field is not null then 'T3,' else '' end as result

from T1 
left outer join T2 on ...
left outer join T3 on ...
```