# Identify which where clause condition was used to get the record in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause, sqlperformance

I am writing a query wherein there are multiple conditions in where clause and want to identify which "where" clause condition was used to get the particular record.

I have pasted an example below but its not working for me for 2 reasons,

1. There are around 10 conditions in "where" clause and they are heavy ones. Its taking lot of time to execute mainly because of the subquery used.
2. It can have multiple conditions matched in "where" clause to get a record.

Any idea how can we implement this. I am using MSSQL.

```
select
column1,
column2,
column3,
CASE
  WHEN CONDITION1 THEN 'Condition1 met'
  WHEN 
    (select count(t.column2) from table t
      where t.column1 = parent.column1
      group by t.column2 
    ) IS NOT NULL THEN 'Condition2 met'
END as conditionsUsed
from table
where
Condition1
OR
(select count(t.column2) from table t
where
t.column1 = parent.column1
group by t.column2 ) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: What would you expect if multiple conditions are met?

Comment: Then it should be able to display like Condtion1,Condition2 in select

Comment: Then you'll need to use separate `CASE` expressions for each. You could then use `CONCAT_WS` to concatenate and delimit the values.

Comment: A better example would probably use `OR` in the `WHERE` clause instead of `AND`, since it's trivially easy to answer for the `AND` case - all of them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. I have updated the example. I am using OR only in where clause

Comment: @Larnu we can use '+' as concatenation rather than  CONCAT_WS. I have got this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202551/concatenate-the-result-of-multiple-case-when-statement

Comment: The advantage of `CONCAT_WS` is you can just do `CONCAT_WS(',',expr1, expr2, expr3)`, rather than something like `STUFF(ISNULL(',' + expr1) + ISNULL(',' + expr2) +ISNULL(',' + expr3),1,1,'')` @Adityayadav .

Comment: For the subquery I have created one temp table and am using it in place of subquery. The  performance has improved but still lot to cover.